# Margin-bottom not moving after a certain amount of px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move the margins of an image, but after changing it to 300 px, it doesn't move up anymore.

I have tried increasing the bottom margin, but it didn't work.
Here is my code:

```js
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0];

function eat() {
  alert('I am going to eat now. Burgers are DELICIOUS');
  img.style.padding = "5px";
  img.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

function movetomouth1() {
  img.style.marginLeft = "-10px";
  img.style.marginBottom = "300px";
}
```

```html
<img src="burger.jpg" onclick="movetomouth1();">
```

Please ask for more code if you think I haven't included enough.

I want it to move closer up the page than it already is.

Comment: Manipulating margins isn't a very effective way to move an element. Have you tried changing the actual positioning? Ie `top`, `left`, etc with `position:absolute` ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: No Phil, I will try that thank you.

Comment: what size is your image ?

Comment: do you want to hide the image after move?

Comment: Size:10x10 px

Not yet, Vinesh. I will do that later. First, I need to move the image.

Comment: Phil, I tried your way, it worked! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

margin can't work, use top / left, and don't forget using position= relative.

```js
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0];

function movetomouth1() {
  img.style.left = "-10px";
  img.style.top = "-10px";
}
```

```css
img {
  position: relative;
  width : 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="burger.jpg" onclick="movetomouth1();" />
```